# RewriteRule RewriteCond в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, веб-сервер

Ситуация такая. На просторах интернета нашел указание .htaccess с использованием mod_rewrite на "завязку" всех вопросов на один файл index.php

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Надо: исключить из этой конструкции файлы типов *.css и* .js. Сам я с файлом htaccess на **этом** уровне работаю впервые (addDefaultCharset не в счет)

Дословно со слов автора: *Данная запись означает буквально следующее: если запрошенный URL-адрес не является файлом, не является символической ссылкой и не является директорией, то подменить виртуальный адрес файлом index.php. При этом, суперглобальная переменная PHP

```
  **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**
```

будет содержать именно запрошенный виртуальный адрес.*

Мои рассуждения:

1. RewriteCond - формирует определенное правило, по которому будет делаться редирект
2. %{REQUEST_FILENAME} - сама строка запроса
3. -s, -l, -d - специальные параметры, проверяющие на "ненулевость" файла, символичную ссылку, каталог. Т.е. если строка запроса указывает на **существующие** папку или файл, то редиректа не будет
4. Последние 2 строки - выполняют сам редирект

**Объясните** мне, как надо записать правило, чтобы из редиректа убрать файлы css, js.

Просьба: сообщения типа **гугл в помощь**, **поищи в интернете** не писать. Мне нужно объяснение по-человечески. т.е. **полный** разбор такого правила. Мне надо не тупо скопипастить, а **понять** логику работы, чтобы в дальнейшем было меньше вопросов.

Всем откликнувшимся заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Пояснение: Если это не симлинки [и] не файл [и] не директория, то производится виртуальный редирект на `/index.php`

#### Обновление

Использование белого списка.

```
RewriteEngine on  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(?!css$|js$|jpeg$|jpg$|png$|gif$|ico$|font$|map$)[^.]+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !robots\.txt$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Пояснение: Если это не файлы с расширениями css, js,... [и] не файл `robots.txt`, то производится виртуальный редирект на `/index.php`.

Comment: т.е. в скобках какую смысловую нагрузку несет знак вопроса в данном выражии?

Кстати, это я делаю для ЧПУ(человеко-понятного УРЛ). все запросы обрабатывать через пхп, но игнорировать css-js

Comment: т.е. На данный момент у меня даже вместо того, чтобы вернуть содержимое файла стилей (css) сервер возвращает обработанный файл index.php Хотелось бы, чтобы загружался файл стилей...

Comment: мне надо, чтобы css js обрабатывались стандартно. Млин... Как бы это объяснить...
Т.е.:   
1. При загрузке страницы через браузер Google Chrome, в инструментах разработчика я смотрю что именно грузит браузер.  
2. При просмотре содержимого файла style.css - получаю обработанный index.php  
Мне необходимо, чтобы загрузка файла style.css проходила стандартным образом, т.е. браузер получал именно тот файл css, который указан в линке.

Только что попробовал ваш вариант - возвращается тот же самый index.php

Comment: @garmayev Обновил ответ. Вам необходимо использовать стандартный конфиг.

К сожалению, Apache уже давно не использую, потому проверяю правила [здесь](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: Большое спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ

Comment: @garmayev Если у Вас не CMS со своими "законами", а какой-нибудь фреймворк с нормальным роутингом по урлу, можно попробовать ужесточить правила - создать белый список. К примеру, разрешить только файл index.php (она же едина точка входа) и некоторую статику. К примеру, css/js/изображения/font. Попробуем?

Comment: @garmayev Дело в том, что при данном раскладе, если, к примеру, злоумышленник разместит в папке со статикой php-файл, то он в обязательном порядке выполнится.