# Перенаправление запроса в index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте, суть такова.
Есть сайт, который работает на параметрах `GET`.
И он на нескольких языках.
Через `.htaccess` сделал ссылку такого вида: `index.php?lang=ru` на такую: `/ru/`.

Так вот теперь, когда я делаю запрос `GET` на другой параметр, пример: `/ru/?search=text`.
То, он не работает, нужно обращаться напрямую к `index.php?search=text`, чтобы он заработал.

Я как понял, это решается через `.htaccess`.

Мой код:

```
RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ][aA-zZ])/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Пробовал написать еще один `Rule` такой:

```
RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ][aA-zZ])/\?search=(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&search=$2 [L]
```

Никакого результата.
Я не спец в .htaccess, подскажите пожалуйста, что-то не так сделал.

Comment: Делайте роутер на php с единой точкой входа, куда будут все запросы поступать. Строка запроса по которому обратились к серверу лежит в `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: @Visman можете пример написать, в ответе, я просто не особо шарю в `.htaccess`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/403181/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453303/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545435/186083